# Flutter and android_intent_plus - use Zebra DataWedge API

Tags: android, flutter, datawedge

Would someone be able to tell what am I doing wrong?

[DataWedge API Documentation](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-2/guide/api/)

For testing I did something like this:

```dart
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
            action: 'com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION',
            arguments: <String, dynamic>{
              'com.symbol.datawedge.api.SWITCH_TO_PROFILE': "aztdemo2",
            },
          );
          await intent.launch();
        },
      ),
```

but... I'm getting an error that there is `no Activity to handle Intent`

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION (has extras) }, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION (has extras) }
```

Should I configure a profile to get this working?